# Why am I getting errors populating fields working with Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

I'm working with Sequelize on an Apollo-Server backend. So far it's been straightforward, but I'm now experiencing a bit of an issue refactoring my code. Specifically, I'm having trouble populating certain fields.

Looking at the code snippets I included, both the first and second versions of the `comment` query work as expected. However, the third and fourth result in `Error: missing FROM-clause entry for table \"votes->votedBy\"` and `Error: Include unexpected. Element has to be either a Model, an Association or an object.` errors respectively.

I have to populate the `User` field multiple times (`addedBy, commentedBy, votedBy`). The same goes for Vote, so rather then having to repeatedly type out all their logic, I decided to store them in the respective variables, as seen below. What I've noticed is if I use only one instance of the stored fields variables (`commentVersionTwo`) it works. Any additional use of the fields variables (`commentVersionThree` and `commentVersionFour`) and it breaks. What am I missing here?

**User and Vote Fields**

```
import models from '../models';

const { Profile, User, Vote } = models;

export const userFields = {
  model: User,
  include: {
    model: Profile,
    as: 'profile',
  },
};

export const voteFields = {
  model: Vote,
  as: 'votes',
  include: {
    as: 'votedBy',
    ...userFields,
  },
};
```

**Comment Query**

```
import { userFields, voteFields } from '../populate-fields';

export default {
  Query: {
    commentVersionOne: (
      parent,
      { commentId },
      { models: { Comment, Vote, User, Profile } }
    ) => {
      return Comment.findByPk(commentId, {
        include: [
          { 
            as: 'commentedBy',
            model: User,
            include: {
              model: Profile,
              as: 'profile',
            }
          },
          {
            model: Vote,
            as: 'votes',
            include: {
              as: 'votedBy',
              model: User,
              include: {
                model: Profile,
                as: 'profile'
              }
            }
          },
        ],
      })
        .then((foundComment) => foundComment.get({ plain: true }))
        .catch((error) => {
          throw new Error(error.message);
        });
    },

    commentVersionTwo: (
      parent,
      { commentId },
      { models: { Comment, Vote, User, Profile } }
    ) => {
      return Comment.findByPk(commentId, {
        include: [
          { 
            as: 'commentedBy',
            ...userFields
          },
          {
            model: Vote,
            as: 'votes',
            include: {
              as: 'votedBy',
              model: User,
              include: {
                model: Profile,
                as: 'profile'
              }
            }
          },
        ],
      })
        .then((foundComment) => foundComment.get({ plain: true }))
        .catch((error) => {
          throw new Error(error.message);
        });
    },

    // Error: missing FROM-clause entry for table \"votes->votedBy\"
    commentVersionThree: (
      parent,
      { commentId },
      { models: { Comment, Vote, User, Profile } }
    ) => {
      return Comment.findByPk(commentId, {
        include: [
          { 
            as: 'commentedBy',
            ...userFields
          },
          {
            model: Vote,
            as: 'votes',
            include: {
              as: 'votedBy',
              ...userFields
            }
          },
        ],
      })
        .then((foundComment) => foundComment.get({ plain: true }))
        .catch((error) => {
          throw new Error(error.message);
        });
    },

    // Error: Include unexpected. Element has to be either a Model, an Association or an object.
    commentVersionFour: (
      parent,
      { commentId },
      { models: { Comment } }
    ) => {
      return Comment.findByPk(commentId, {
        include: [
          { 
            as: 'commentedBy',
            ...userFields
          },
          {...voteFields}
        ],
      })
        .then((foundComment) => foundComment.get({ plain: true }))
        .catch((error) => {
          throw new Error(error.message);
        });
    },
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it to work. So, rather than use plain objects storing the respective fields, I used functions which return said (fields) objects.